# I want to color the spam inside the article

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want tto write a program. This program will find and color the spam inside the article. I found Spam, but I can't color it. I wrote a bad code. I am aware.

My codes this way:

```js
  $("button").click(function(){
    var source = $("p").text();
    function findSpam(txt){
      if(!txt) return `no string...`;
      let spamWords = ["codeblogger","truecodes","metus","xxx"];
      for(let i = 0; i < spamWords.length; i++){
        if(txt.toLowerCase().includes(spamWords[i])){
          source.indexOf(spamWords[i]).style.color = "blue"; // not work :)
          return 'This article has spam.';
        }else{
          return `This article has not spam.`;
        }
      } 
    };
    alert(findSpam(source));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="box">
      <h1 class="text-center mt-5 pb-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p id="text" >
       ........... I shorten the article.
        
        Integer euismod consequat ex sed feugiat. Morbi sed sem in ipsum scelerisque 
        elementum. Phasellus et tristique odio. Ut lacus dolor, tincidunt eget magna 
        sed, dignissim lobortis risus. Vivamus volutpat vel dui ut elementum. Maecenas 
        ultricies, erat sed egestas finibus, tellus nibh hendrerit sem, id imperdiet 
        est lorem sit amet lacus. Quisque scelerisque nisl id sapien porttitor, tristique 
        pharetra mi iaculis. Vestibulum ac arcu lobortis, posuere dolor non, condimentum 
        est. Nam non efficitur nunc, fringilla sollicitudin ante. Curabitur quis metus 
        tellus truecodes codeblogger codeblogger xxx.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">FIND SPAM</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

**In addition:**

The code finds spam. No problem. But I also want to find the number of spam. How do I do that. I have tried this way:

```js
  $("button").click(function(){
    var source = $("p").text();
    function findSpam(txt){
      let totalSpam = 0;
      if(!txt) return `no string...`;
      let spamWords = ["codeblogger","truecodes","metus","xxx"];
      for(let i = 0; i < spamWords.length; i++){
        if(txt.toLowerCase().includes(spamWords[i])){
          totalSpam ++;
        }
      }
      return totalSpam; 
    };
    alert(`Total spam: ${findSpam(source)}`); 
    // output: 4. But there are a total of 8 in the article.
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div id="box">
      <h1 class="text-center mt-5 pb-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
      <p id="text" >
        .......
        Integer euismod consequat ex sed feugiat. Morbi sed sem in ipsum scelerisque 
        elementum. Phasellus et tristique odio. Ut lacus dolor, tincidunt eget magna 
        sed, dignissim lobortis risus. Vivamus volutpat vel dui ut elementum. Maecenas 
        ultricies, erat sed egestas finibus, tellus nibh hendrerit sem, id imperdiet 
        est lorem sit amet lacus. Quisque scelerisque nisl id sapien porttitor, tristique 
        pharetra mi iaculis. Vestibulum ac arcu lobortis, posuere dolor non, condimentum 
        est. Nam non efficitur nunc, fringilla sollicitudin ante. Curabitur quis metus 
        tellus truecodes codeblogger codeblogger xxx xxx xxx.
      </p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">FIND SPAM</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var source = $("p").text();
  var newSource = source;
  var result = 'This article has not spam.';

  if (!source) alert("no string...");
  let spamWords = ["codeblogger", "truecodes", "metus", "xxx"];
  for (let i = 0; i < spamWords.length; i++) {
    if (source.toLowerCase().includes(spamWords[i])) {
      newSource = newSource.replace(spamWords[i], '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline;">' + spamWords[i] + '</span>');
      result = 'This article has spam.';
    }
  }

  $("#text").html(newSource);
  console.log(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-5 pb-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p id="text">
      ........... I shorten the article. Integer euismod consequat ex sed feugiat. Morbi sed sem in ipsum scelerisque elementum. Phasellus et tristique odio. Ut lacus dolor, tincidunt eget magna sed, dignissim lobortis risus. Vivamus volutpat vel dui ut elementum.
      Maecenas ultricies, erat sed egestas finibus, tellus nibh hendrerit sem, id imperdiet est lorem sit amet lacus. Quisque scelerisque nisl id sapien porttitor, tristique pharetra mi iaculis. Vestibulum ac arcu lobortis, posuere dolor non, condimentum
      est. Nam non efficitur nunc, fringilla sollicitudin ante. Curabitur quis metus tellus truecodes codeblogger codeblogger xxx.
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">FIND SPAM</button>
  </div>
</div>



</script>
```

Comment: Why not post a snippet?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how to do :)

Comment: If you had clicked "Copy snippet to answer" it would be automatically. Now you have to edit and click the `[<>]` snippet editor button

Comment: You only highlight the first spam occurrence

Comment: Merci for info. I am going to update my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to count the 7 instances:

```js
let spamWords = ["codeblogger", "truecodes", "metus", "xxx"];
function findSpam(txt) {
  let totalSpam = 0;
  if (!txt) return `no string...`;
  spamWords.forEach(word => {
    var re = new RegExp(word, "gi");
    totalSpam += txt.match(re).length;
  })
  return totalSpam;
};

$("button").click(function() {
  var source = $("p").text();
  console.log(`Total spam: ${findSpam(source)}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-5 pb-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p id="text">
      ....... Integer euismod consequat ex sed feugiat. Morbi sed sem in ipsum scelerisque elementum. Phasellus et tristique odio. Ut lacus dolor, tincidunt eget magna sed, dignissim lobortis risus. Vivamus volutpat vel dui ut elementum. Maecenas ultricies,
      erat sed egestas finibus, tellus nibh hendrerit sem, id imperdiet est lorem sit amet lacus. Quisque scelerisque nisl id sapien porttitor, tristique pharetra mi iaculis. Vestibulum ac arcu lobortis, posuere dolor non, condimentum est. Nam non efficitur
      nunc, fringilla sollicitudin ante. Curabitur quis metus tellus truecodes codeblogger codeblogger XXX xxx xxx.
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">FIND SPAM</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I did not have time to fix my looping to replace:

```js
let spamWords = ["codeblogger", "truecodes", "metus", "xxx"];

function findSpam(txt) {
  let totalSpam = 0;
  if (!txt) return `no string...`;
  spamWords.forEach(word => {
    var re = new RegExp(word, "gi");
    totalSpam += txt.toLowerCase().match(re).length;
  })
  return totalSpam;
};

function replaceSpam() {
  let txt = $("p").text().toLowerCase()
  spamWords.forEach(word => {
    let parts = txt.split(/\s/);
    if (parts.indexOf(word) != -1) {
      var re = new RegExp(word, "gi");
      txt.match(re).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i).forEach(uWord => {
        var replaced = $("p").text().replace(
          new RegExp(uWord, "g"),
          function(w) {
            return `<span class="spam">${w}</span>`
          }
        );
        console.log(replaced)
        $("p").html(replaced)
      })
    }
    txt = $("p").text().toLowerCase()
  })
}
$("button").click(function() {
  var source = $("p").text();
  console.log(`Total spam: ${findSpam(source)}`);
  replaceSpam(source)
});
```

```css
.spam {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="box">
    <h1 class="text-center mt-5 pb-3">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <p id="text">
      ....... Integer euismod consequat ex sed feugiat. Morbi sed sem in ipsum scelerisque elementum. Phasellus et tristique odio. Ut lacus dolor, tincidunt eget magna sed, dignissim lobortis risus. Vivamus volutpat vel dui ut elementum. Maecenas ultricies,
      erat sed egestas finibus, tellus nibh hendrerit sem, id imperdiet est lorem sit amet lacus. Quisque scelerisque nisl id sapien porttitor, tristique pharetra mi iaculis. Vestibulum ac arcu lobortis, posuere dolor non, condimentum est. Nam non efficitur
      nunc, fringilla sollicitudin ante. Curabitur quis metus tellus truecodes codeBlogger codeblogger XXX xxx xxx.
    </p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-block">FIND SPAM</button>
  </div>
</div>
```